# Comparing that an object belongs to other object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I have two objects below.

As you see, how can I check the **objectB** belongs to the **objectA** or not because all the fields of both object are the same, and the **casts field** of the **objectB** is a child of the **casts field** of the **objectA**.

```
ObjectA = { 
  title: 'Alita: Battle Angel',
  year: '2019',
  casts:
   [ 'Rosa Salazar',
     'Christoph Waltz',
     'Jennifer Connelly',
     'Mahershala Ali',
     'Michelle Rodriguez',
     'Casper Van Dien' ] }

ObjectB = {
  title: 'Alita: Battle Angel',
  casts: 
     [ 'Rosa Salazar', 
       ' Christoph Waltz' ],
  year: '2019' },
```

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you for your keyword. I'll do some research.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Comment: I think a deep compare of objects would help ... but since the data isn't exact you'll have to write special conditions

Comment: Hi @NguyenHoang, Kindly check this https://npm.runkit.com/is-subset. Hope it will help you.

Comment: I implemented a test for your objects: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/6aqhcrp8/ - Please note that the leading space in `' Christoph Waltz'` would make the test false

Answer (score 1):

The function `isObjectBelong` receives two arguments:

- `rootObject` - object containing `cats` string array property
- `childObject` - object containing `cats` string array property

Function returns `true` if `childObject.cats` contains subset of `rootObject.cats`, and `false` otherwise.

```
const isObjectBelong = (rootObject, childObject) =>
    childObject.casts.every(r => rootObject.casts.includes(r));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
ObjectA = {
  title: 'Alita: Battle Angel',
  year: '2019',
  casts: ['Rosa Salazar',
    'Christoph Waltz',
    'Jennifer Connelly',
    'Mahershala Ali',
    'Michelle Rodriguez',
    'Casper Van Dien'
  ]
}

ObjectB = {
  title: 'Alita: Battle Angel',
  casts: ['Rosa Salazar',
    'Christoph Waltz'
  ],
  year: '2019'
}
ObjectC = {
  title: 'Alita: Battle Angel',
  casts: ['Rosa Salazar',
    'Christoph'
  ],
  year: '2019'
}
ObjectD = {
  title: 'Alita: Battle',
  casts: ['Rosa Salazar',
    'Christoph Waltz'
  ],
  year: '2019'
}
ObjectE = {
  title: 'Alita: Battle Angel',
  casts: ['Rosa Salazar',
    'Christoph Waltz'
  ],
  year: '2018'
}

function compare(obj1, obj2) {

  if (obj1.title == obj2.title && obj1.year == obj2.year) {
    for (i = 0; i < obj2.casts.length; i++) {

      if (obj1.casts.indexOf(obj2.casts[i]) == -1) {
        console.log('obj2 is not a part of obj 1');
        return;
      }
    }
    console.log('obj2 is a part of obj 1');
  } else {
    console.log('obj2 is not a part of obj 1');
  }
}
compare(ObjectA, ObjectB)
compare(ObjectA, ObjectC)
compare(ObjectA, ObjectD)
compare(ObjectA, ObjectE)
```

Answer (score 1):

For your specific use case something like the following should work.

```js
ObjectA = {
  title: 'Alita: Battle Angel',
  year: '2019',
  casts: ['Rosa Salazar',
    'Christoph Waltz',
    'Jennifer Connelly',
    'Mahershala Ali',
    'Michelle Rodriguez',
    'Casper Van Dien'
  ]
}

ObjectB = {
  title: 'Alita: Battle Angel',
  casts: ['Rosa Salazar',
    'Christoph Waltz'
  ],
  year: '2019'
}

ObjectC = {
  title: 'Alita: Battle Angel',
  casts: ['Rosa Salazar',
    'Someone else'
  ],
  year: '2019'
}

const isSubset = (parentObject, childObject, isProper) => {
  if ((parentObject.title === childObject.title) && (parentObject.year === childObject.year)) {
    const casts = childObject.casts.filter(cast => parentObject.casts.find(originalCast => originalCast === cast))
    return isProper ? (casts.length === childObject.casts.length) : Boolean(casts.length)
  }
  return false
}

console.log(isSubset(ObjectA, ObjectB))
console.log(isSubset(ObjectA, ObjectC))
console.log(isSubset(ObjectA, ObjectB, true))
console.log(isSubset(ObjectA, ObjectC, true))
```

I've added a little bit checking and an additional parameter called isProper. isProper will check, whether all the cast in the child exists in the parent. When you add more check your code is less likely to fail.